# Problem in converting JSON String Containing multiple Array to C# Array of Array

Tags: javascript

I have created 2 array in Javascript and then stringified both arrays and then merged the stringified string into a variable to send from client Side to a C# MVC controller but it failed to deserialize into array of array at server side.

```
var personMainArr = [objStu];
var personimageArr = [imageData];
var jSONdata= JSON.stringify(personMainArr) + JSON.stringify(personimageArr)
```

The JSON string received at server side is:

```
[{"Person_Name":"sdfsaf","Person_DOB":"21/08/2019",}][{"PersonImage_FileName":"come.png","PersonImage_FileExtension":"image/png"}]
```

I want an array of string at server side in C# which should contain both of above array after separation.

Comment: Why not merge the object and send ONE object with two keys?

Comment: How can we assign Keys to these object in javascript and how will identify individually at C# Controller Side

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
var personMainArr = [objStu];
var personimageArr = [imageData];
var jSONdata = Object.assign(personMainArr, personimageArr)
console.log(JSON.stringify(jSONdata, null, 4))
```